# node converting callback to async results in a paused execution

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, cookies, callback, puppeteer

Beginner JS here. I plan on gathering cookies from multiple sites so I wanted to convert the following to a Node.js helper function.

```js
const chrome = require('chrome-cookies-secure');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const url = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com';
const getCookies = (callback) => {
    chrome.getCookies(url, 'puppeteer', function(err, cookies) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, 'error');
            return
        }
        console.log(cookies, 'cookies');
        callback(cookies);
    }, 'Profile 6') // e.g. 'Profile 2'
}

// find profiles at ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome

getCookies(async (cookies) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setCookie(...cookies);
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitFor(5000);
    browser.close()
});
```

The above code launches puppeteer just fine with the cookie from Chrome.

My attempt below to make this a function so I can easily pass any url is below.

helper.js

```js
const chrome = require('chrome-cookies-secure');
module.exports.get_cookies = async (url) => {
    chrome.getCookies(url, 'puppeteer', function(err, cookies) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, 'error');
            return
        }
        console.log(cookies, 'cookies');
        return Promise.resolve(cookies);
    }, 'Profile 1') // e.g. 'Profile 2'
}
```

stackoverflow.js

```js
run = async () => {
    var helper = require('./helper.js')
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const url = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com/';
    var cookies = await helper.get_cookies(url);
    console.log('got cookies');
    await page.setCookie(...cookies);
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitFor(5000);
    browser.close()
}

run()
```

The problem is the execution just pauses after console logs the cookies. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. When I ^C, js does not tell me what it was executing, it just breaks.

**Update**

Thanks to [Molda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491727/node-converting-callback-to-async-results-in-a-paused-execution#comment105157998_59491727), I was able to get return cookies. Now trying to handle Promise rejection.

```
got cookies
(node:53555) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: page.setCookie is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at run (/Users/paragbaxi/Documents/GitHub/safeshifter/libs/example_local_cookies.js:39:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:53555) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:53555) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[
  {
    name: 'token',
    value: '3.oUjlqQnJzd0UiLCJleHBpcmVzIjoiMjAxOS0xMi0yNVQwMzo0NTo0My4wMDBaIiwibG9nZ2VkT3V0IjpmYWxzZSwic2NvcGVzIjpbIioiLCJlbWFpbCJdfQ==',
    expires: 13284873942637332,
    domain: '.stackoverflow.com',
    path: '/',
    Secure: true
  }
] cookies
```

Comment: The function `get_cookies` must return a `Promise` where you call `resolve(cookies)`  This line `return cookies;` in helper.js does not do what you think.

Comment: Updated thank you. Now having `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to LJHarb and Molda

```
function getCookies(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      chrome.getCookies(url, 'puppeteer', function (err, cookies) {
        if (err) { reject(err); }
        else { resolve(cookies); }
      }, chrome_profile);
    });
  }
```

Comment: You don't need to use the `async/await` in the promise.